# next and back button in tkinter

Tags: python, file, csv, tkinter

I just have this piece of code that gets the next line from a file per each press but I could not figure out how to make the back button.
is that possible to do?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

f = open('sentence.txt', 'r')

label = tk.Label(root,text="")
label.pack()
tk.Button(root,text="Click for next",
          command=lambda: label.config(text=next(f))).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"is that possible to do?"***: Yes, but there is no `previous(f)`, you have to implement it yourself. Relevant [os.lseek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.lseek)

Comment: @stovfl oh thanks!, i will consider it. the problem is that I am reading lines from file while pressing on a button. but after the file run out of lines, the text disappears from the label. is there any why to make the button work in a loop?

Comment: ***"o make the button work in a loop?"***: You mean if you reach the end of file, continue with the **first line**. Yes, the same relevant link.